# Questions on Security of bots on teams

Tags: node.js, security, botframework, microsoft-teams, exploit

Our team has created a chatbot with microsoft bot framework.(Nodejs) and the chatbot is deployed in teams via its manifest by the tenant admin of an organization.

I had a few questions on securities-(Questions are just related to teams bot)

1)How easy would it be for a malicious user to emulate the teams channel endpoint.? (The bot uses 3 layers of verification in the OnMessage activity handler. (Graph Api and some other organization specific ones)
But the problem is we are using teamsinfo.getmembers(context) API call to get the email id of the user from teams to go through these verification.

2)Is the teamsinfo.getmembers(context) vulnerable? Could any malicious user be able to provide a duplicate exact turn context of any existing authentic user?

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting question, I believe providing the malicious turnContext is not easy for any attacker. The request goes to bot framework services in encrypted format which have a various level of security running on. If you have an outbound firewall blocking traffic from your bot to the Internet you can [whitelist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-faq-security?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#which-specific-urls-do-i-need-to-whitelist-in-my-corporate-firewall-to-access-bot-framework-services) the URL as per standards. You can also implement the authentication in your Bot for adding one more layer of security.
You can check the [security guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-faq-security?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#which-specific-urls-do-i-need-to-whitelist-in-my-corporate-firewall-to-access-bot-framework-services) for Bots.

Comment: This answer covers a lot, so I'll just 'append' rather than add a new one, but I've got a blog post that you might find useful to understand some of the "under the hood" of bots, at https://hilton.giesenow.com/how-bot-calls-actually-work

Comment: Great @HiltonGiesenow This is really helpful to understand the basic flow of Bot

Comment: Great @HiltonGiesenow, Great blog ,As you rightly said Microsoft documentations although its really good,but its a bit difficult to get grasp on things especially for the beginners.You might want to add blogs on dialog Flows and Session storage. Maybe things like adding transcript with custom middlewares.  Also do you happen to have any simpler explaination of OAuth2.0 ,Microsoft doc confuses me.

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Bot is hosted on Azure services, in the app service there is CORS policy, are you talking about blocking it there?(Outbound firewall to block traffic to bot). Our bot at the moment is not registered with Bot framework Channel. Also not yet enabled OAuth 2.0 for teams.  At the moment we have to 2 exposed API keys directline's and Teams one.

Comment: glad to hear it's useful, and thanks for the great topic suggestions, will look into those